# Syntax error, unrecognized expression ao chamar uma função com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocompletar

Estou usando em meu projeto o EasyAutocomplete, que está funcionando perfeitamente.
Porem estou com este erro em meu projeto e não consegui encontra-lo. Se eu tiro o JQuery o erro não acontece. Segue meu import do JQuery que está sendo feito no 'head' e esta chamando o arquivo JQuery de dentro de um dos diretórios do meu projeto.
Segue as chamadas que estão dentro da tag 'head':

```
<link href="css/easy-autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

Este é meu script que executa o EasyAutocomplete(funcionando):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var options = {
        url: function(phrase) {
            return "LoadProduct?QUERY=" + phrase
        },

        getValue: "description",

        list: {
            match: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },

        theme: "square"
    };

    $("#buscador").easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

E este é o erro que não sei de onde vem:

```
jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #function (a) {
                for (var b = this.length; b--;)if (this[b] === a)return !0;
                return !1
            }
```

Este é o código JQuery para o qual o console do chrome está apontando como causa do erro:

```
throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression:            "+a)},fa.uniqueSort=function(a){var b,d=  [],e=0,f=0;if(l=!c.detectDuplicates,k=!c.sortStable&&a.slice(0),a.sort(B),l)  {while(b=a[f++])b===a[f]&&(e=d.push(f));while(e--)a.splice(d[e],1)}return   k=null,a},e=fa.getText=function(a){var b,c="",d=0,f=a.nodeType;if(f)  {if(1===f||9===f||11===f){if("string"==typeof a.textContent)return     a.textContent;for(a=a.firstChild;a;a=a.nextSibling)c+=e(a)}else     if(3===f||4===f)return a.nodeValue}else while(b=a[d++])c+=e(b);return    c},d=fa.selectors={cacheLength:50,createPseudo:ha,match:W,attrHandle:{},find:   {},relative:{">":{dir:"parentNode",first:!0}," ":{dir:"parentNode"},"+":   {dir:"previousSibling",first:!0},"~":{dir:"previousSibling"}},preFilter:{ATTR:function(a){return a[1]=a[1].replace(ba,ca),a[3]=(a[3]||a[4]||a[5]||"").replace(ba,ca),"~="===a[2]&&(a[3]=" "+a[3]+" "),a.slice(0,4)},CHILD:function(a){return a[1]=a[1].toLowerCase(),"nth"===a[1].slice(0,3)?(a[3]||fa.error(a[0]),a[4]=+(a[4]?a[5]+(a[6]||1):2*("even"===a[3]||"odd"===a[3])),a[5]=+(a[7]+a[8]||"odd"===a[3])):a[3]&&fa.error(a[0]),a},PSEUDO:function(a){var b,c=!a[6]&&a[2];return W.CHILD.test(a[0])?null:(a[3]?a[2]=a[4]||a[5]||"":c&&U.test(c)&&(b=g(c,!0))&&(b=c.indexOf(")",c.length-b)-c.length)&&(a[0]=a[0].slice(0,b),a[2]=c.slice(0,b)),a.slice(0,3))}},filter:{TAG:function(a){var b=a.replace(ba,ca).toLowerCase();return"*"===a?function(){return!0}:function(a){return a.nodeName&&a.nodeName.toLowerCase()===b}},CLASS:function(a){var b=y[a+" "];return b||(b=new RegExp("(^|"+L+")"+a+"("+L+"|$)"))&&y(a,function(a){return b.test("string"==typeof a.className&&a.className||"undefined"!=typeof a.getAttribute&&a.getAttribute("class")||"")})},ATTR:function(a,b,c){return function(d){var e=fa.attr(d,a);return null==e?"!="===b:b?(e+="","="===b?e===c:"!="===b?e!==c:"^="===b?c&&0===e.indexOf(c):"*="===b?c&&e.indexOf(c)>-1:"$="===b?c&&e.slice(-c.length)===c:"~="===b?(" "+e.replace(P," ")+" ").indexOf(c)>-1:"|="===b?e===c||e.slice(0,c.length+1)===c+"-":!1):!0}},CHILD:function(a,b,c,d,e){var f="nth"!==a.slice(0,3),g="last"!==a.slice(-4),h="of-type"===b;return 1===d&&0===e?function(a){return!!a.parentNode}:function(b,c,i){var j,k,l,m,n,o,p=f!==g?"nextSibling":"previousSibling",q=b.parentNode,r=h&&b.nodeName.toLowerCase(),s=!i&&!h,t=!1;if(q){if(f){while(p){m=b;while(m=m[p])if(h?m.nodeName.toLowerCase()===r:1===m.nodeType)return!1;o=p="only"===a&&!o&&"nextSibling"}return!0}if(o=[g?q.firstChild:q.lastChild],g&&s){m=q,l=m[u]||(m[u]={}),k=l[m.uniqueID]||(l[m.uniqueID]={}),j=k[a]||[],n=j[0]===w&&j[1],t=n&&j[2],m=n&&q.childNodes[n];while(m=++n&&m&&m[p]||(t=n=0)||o.pop())if(1===m.nodeType&&++t&&m===b){k[a]=[w,n,t];break}}else if(s&&(m=b,l=m[u]||(m[u]={}),k=l[m.uniqueID]||(l[m.uniqueID]={}),j=k[a]||[],n=j[0]===w&&j[1],t=n),t===!1)while(m=++n&&m&&m[p]||(t=n=0)||o.pop())if((h?m.nodeName.toLowerCase()===r:1===m.nodeType)&&++t&&(s&&(l=m[u]||(m[u]={}),k=l[m.uniqueID]||(l[m.uniqueID]={}),k[a]=[w,t]),m===b))break;return t-=e,t===d||t%d===0&&t/d>=0}}},PSEUDO:function(a,b){var c,e=d.pseudos[a]||d.setFilters[a.toLowerCase()]||fa.error("unsupported pseudo: "+a);return e[u]?e(b):e.length>1?(c=[a,a,"",b],d.setFilters.hasOwnProperty(a.toLowerCase())?ha(function(a,c){var d,f=e(a,b),g=f.length;while(g--)d=J(a,f[g]),a[d]=!(c[d]=f[g])}):function(a){return e(a,0,c)}):e}},pseudos:{not:ha(function(a){var b=[],c=[],d=h(a.replace(Q,"$1"));return d[u]?ha(function(a,b,c,e){var f,g=d(a,null,e,[]),h=a.length;while(h--)(f=g[h])&&(a[h]=!(b[h]=f))}):function(a,e,f){return b[0]=a,d(b,null,f,c),b[0]=null,!c.pop()}}),has:ha(function(a){return function(b){return fa(a,b).length>0}}),contains:ha(function(a){return a=a.replace(ba,ca),function(b){return(b.textContent||b.innerText||e(b)).indexOf(a)>-1}}),lang:ha(function(a){return V.test(a||"")||fa.error("unsupported lang: "+a),a=a.replace(ba,ca).toLowerCase(),function(b){var c;do if(c=p?b.lang:b.getAttribute("xml:lang")||b.getAttribute("lang"))return c=c.toLowerCase(),c===a||0===c.indexOf(a+"-");while((b=b.parentNode)&&1===b.nodeType);return!1}}),target:function(b){var c=a.location&&a.location.hash;return c&&c.slice(1)===b.id},root:function(a){return a===o},focus:function(a){return a===n.activeElement&&(!n.hasFocus||n.hasFocus())&&!!(a.type||a.href||~a.tabIndex)},enabled:function(a){return a.disabled===!1},disabled:function(a){return a.disabled===!0},checked:function(a){var b=a.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"input"===b&&!!a.checked||"option"===b&&!!a.selected},selected:function(a){return a.parentNode&&a.parentNode.selectedIndex,a.selected===!0},empty:function(a){for(a=a.firstChild;a;a=a.nextSibling)if(a.nodeType<6)return!1;return!0},parent:function(a){return!d.pseudos.empty(a)},header:function(a){return Y.test(a.nodeName)},input:function(a){return X.test(a.nodeName)},button:function(a){var b=a.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"input"===b&&"button"===a.type||"button"===b},text:function(a){var b;return"input"===a.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&"text"===a.type&&(null==(b=a.getAttribute("type"))||"text"===b.toLowerCase())},first:na(function(){return[0]}),last:na(function(a,b){return[b-1]}),eq:na(function(a,b,c){return[0>c?c+b:c]}),even:na(function(a,b){for(var c=0;b>c;c+=2)a.push(c);return a}),odd:na(function(a,b){for(var c=1;b>c;c+=2)a.push(c);return a}),lt:na(function(a,b,c){for(var d=0>c?c+b:c;--d>=0;)a.push(d);return a}),gt:na(function(a,b,c){for(var d=0>c?c+b:c;++d<b;)a.push(d);return a})}},d.pseudos.nth=d.pseudos.eq;for(b in{radio:!0,checkbox:!0,file:!0,password:!0,image:!0})d.pseudos[b]=la(b);for(b in{submit:!0,reset:!0})d.pseudos[b]=ma(b);function pa(){}pa.prototype=d.filters=d.pseudos,d.setFilters=new pa,g=fa.tokenize=function(a,b){var c,e,f,g,h,i,j,k=z[a+" "];if(k)return b?0:k.slice(0);h=a,i=[],j=d.preFilter;while(h){c&&!(e=R.exec(h))||(e&&(h=h.slice(e[0].length)||h),i.push(f=[])),c=!1,(e=S.exec(h))&&(c=e.shift(),f.push({value:c,type:e[0].replace(Q," ")}),h=h.slice(c.length));for(g in d.filter)!(e=W[g].exec(h))||j[g]&&!(e=j[g](e))||(c=e.shift(),f.push({value:c,type:g,matches:e}),h=h.slice(c.length));if(!c)break}return b?h.length:h?fa.error(a):z(a,i).slice(0)};function qa(a){for(var b=0,c=a.length,d="";c>b;b++)d+=a[b].value;return d}function ra(a,b,c){var d=b.dir,e=c&&"parentNode"===d,f=x++;return b.first?function(b,c,f){while(b=b[d])if(1===b.nodeType||e)return a(b,c,f)}:function(b,c,g){var h,i,j,k=[w,f];if(g){while(b=b[d])if((1===b.nodeType||e)&&a(b,c,g))return!0}else while(b=b[d])if(1===b.nodeType||e){if(j=b[u]||(b[u]={}),i=j[b.uniqueID]||(j[b.uniqueID]={}),(h=i[d])&&h[0]===w&&h[1]===f)return k[2]=h[2];if(i[d]=k,k[2]=a(b,c,g))return!0}}}function sa(a){return a.length>1?function(b,c,d){var e=a.length;while(e--)if(!a[e](b,c,d))return!1;return!0}:a[0]}function ta(a,b,c){for(var d=0,e=b.length;e>d;d++)fa(a,b[d],c);return c}function ua(a,b,c,d,e){for(var f,g=[],h=0,i=a.length,j=null!=b;i>h;h++)(f=a[h])&&(c&&!c(f,d,e)||(g.push(f),j&&b.push(h)));return g}function va(a,b,c,d,e,f){return d&&!d[u]&&(d=va(d)),e&&!e[u]&&(e=va(e,f)),ha(function(f,g,h,i){var j,k,l,m=[],n=[],o=g.length,p=f||ta(b||"*",h.nodeType?[h]:h,[]),q=!a||!f&&b?p:ua(p,m,a,h,i),r=c?e||(f?a:o||d)?[]:g:q;if(c&&c(q,r,h,i),d){j=ua(r,n),d(j,[],h,i),k=j.length;while(k--)(l=j[k])&&(r[n[k]]=!(q[n[k]]=l))}if(f){if(e||a){if(e){j=[],k=r.length;while(k--)(l=r[k])&&j.push(q[k]=l);e(null,r=[],j,i)}k=r.length;while(k--)(l=r[k])&&(j=e?J(f,l):m[k])>-1&&(f[j]=!(g[j]=l))}}else r=ua(r===g?r.splice(o,r.length):r),e?e(null,g,r,i):H.apply(g,r)})}function wa(a){for(var b,c,e,f=a.length,g=d.relative[a[0].type],h=g||d.relative[" "],i=g?1:0,k=ra(function(a){return a===b},h,!0),l=ra(function(a){return J(b,a)>-1},h,!0),m=[function(a,c,d){var e=!g&&(d||c!==j)||((b=c).nodeType?k(a,c,d):l(a,c,d));return b=null,e}];f>i;i++)if(c=d.relative[a[i].type])m=[ra(sa(m),c)];else{if(c=d.filter[a[i].type].apply(null,a[i].matches),c[u]){for(e=++i;f>e;e++)if(d.relative[a[e].type])break;return va(i>1&&sa(m),i>1&&qa(a.slice(0,i-1).concat({value:" "===a[i-2].type?"*":""})).replace(Q,"$1"),c,e>i&&wa(a.slice(i,e)),f>e&&wa(a=a.slice(e)),f>e&&qa(a))}m.push(c)}return sa(m)}function xa(a,b){var c=b.length>0,e=a.length>0,f=function(f,g,h,i,k){var l,o,q,r=0,s="0",t=f&&[],u=[],v=j,x=f||e&&d.find.TAG("*",k),y=w+=null==v?1:Math.random()||.1,z=x.length;for(k&&(j=g===n||g||k);s!==z&&null!=(l=x[s]);s++){if(e&&l){o=0,g||l.ownerDocument===n||(m(l),h=!p);while(q=a[o++])if(q(l,g||n,h)){i.push(l);break}k&&(w=y)}c&&((l=!q&&l)&&r--,f&&t.push(l))}if(r+=s,c&&s!==r){o=0;while(q=b[o++])q(t,u,g,h);if(f){if(r>0)while(s--)t[s]||u[s]||(u[s]=F.call(i));u=ua(u)}H.apply(i,u),k&&!f&&u.length>0&&r+b.length>1&&fa.uniqueSort(i)}return k&&(w=y,j=v),t};return c?ha(f):f}return h=fa.compile=function(a,b){var c,d=[],e=[],f=A[a+" "];if(!f){b||(b=g(a)),c=b.length;while(c--)f=wa(b[c]),f[u]?d.push(f):e.push(f);f=A(a,xa(e,d)),f.selector=a}return f},i=fa.select=function(a,b,e,f){var i,j,k,l,m,n="function"==typeof a&&a,o=!f&&g(a=n.selector||a);if(e=e||[],1===o.length){if(j=o[0]=o[0].slice(0),j.length>2&&"ID"===(k=j[0]).type&&c.getById&&9===b.nodeType&&p&&d.relative[j[1].type]){if(b=(d.find.ID(k.matches[0].replace(ba,ca),b)||[])[0],!b)return e;n&&(b=b.parentNode),a=a.slice(j.shift().value.length)}i=W.needsContext.test(a)?0:j.length;while(i--){if(k=j[i],d.relative[l=k.type])break;if((m=d.find[l])&&(f=m(k.matches[0].replace(ba,ca),_.test(j[0].type)&&oa(b.parentNode)||b))){if(j.splice(i,1),a=f.length&&qa(j),!a)return H.apply(e,f),e;break}}}return(n||h(a,o))(f,b,!p,e,!b||_.test(a)&&oa(b.parentNode)||b),e},c.sortStable=u.split("").sort(B).join("")===u,c.detectDuplicates=!!l,m(),c.sortDetached=ia(function(a){return 1&a.compareDocumentPosition(n.createElement("div"))}),ia(function(a){return a.innerHTML="<a href='#'></a>","#"===a.firstChild.getAttribute("href")})||ja("type|href|height|width",function(a,b,c){return c?void 0:a.getAttribute(b,"type"===b.toLowerCase()?1:2)}),c.attributes&&ia(function(a){return a.innerHTML="<input/>",a.firstChild.setAttribute("value",""),""===a.firstChild.getAttribute("value")})||ja("value",function(a,b,c){return c||"input"!==a.nodeName.toLowerCase()?void 0:a.defaultValue}),ia(function(a){return null==a.getAttribute("disabled")})||ja(K,function(a,b,c){var d;return c?void 0:a[b]===!0?b.toLowerCase():(d=a.getAttributeNode(b))&&d.specified?d.value:null}),fa}(a);n.find=t,n.expr=t.selectors,n.expr[":"]=n.expr.pseudos,n.uniqueSort=n.unique=t.uniqueSort,n.text=t.getText,n.isXMLDoc=t.isXML,n.contains=t.contains;var u=function(a,b,c){var d=[],e=void 0!==c;while((a=a[b])&&9!==a.nodeType)if(1===a.nodeType){if(e&&n(a).is(c))break;d.push(a)}return d},v=function(a,b){for(var c=[];a;a=a.nextSibling)1===a.nodeType&&a!==b&&c.push(a);return c},w=n.expr.match.needsContext,x=/^<([\w-]+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>|)$/,y=/^.[^:#\[\.,]*$/;function z(a,b,c){if(n.isFunction(b))return n.grep(a,function(a,d){return!!b.call(a,d,a)!==c});if(b.nodeType)return n.grep(a,function(a){return a===b!==c});if("string"==typeof b){if(y.test(b))return n.filter(b,a,c);b=n.filter(b,a)}return n.grep(a,function(a){return n.inArray(a,b)>-1!==c})}n.filter=function(a,b,c){var d=b[0];return c&&(a=":not("+a+")"),1===b.length&&1===d.nodeType?n.find.matchesSelector(d,a)?[d]:[]:n.find.matches(a,n.grep(b,function(a){return 1===a.nodeType}))},n.fn.extend({find:function(a){var b,c=[],d=this,e=d.length;if("string"!=typeof a)return this.pushStack(n(a).filter(function(){for(b=0;e>b;b++)if(n.contains(d[b],this))return!0}));for(b=0;e>b;b++)n.find(a,d[b],c);return c=this.pushStack(e>1?n.unique(c):c),c.selector=this.selector?this.selector+" "+a:a,c},filter:function(a){return this.pushStack(z(this,a||[],!1))},not:function(a){return this.pushStack(z(this,a||[],!0))},is:function(a){return!!z(this,"string"==typeof a&&w.test(a)?n(a):a||[],!1).length}});var A,B=/^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/,C=n.fn.init=function(a,b,c){var e,f;if(!a)return this;if(c=c||A,"string"==typeof a){if(e="<"===a.charAt(0)&&">"===a.charAt(a.length-1)&&a.length>=3?[null,a,null]:B.exec(a),!e||!e[1]&&b)return!b||b.jquery?(b||c).find(a):this.constructor(b).find(a);if(e[1]){if(b=b instanceof n?b[0]:b,n.merge(this,n.parseHTML(e[1],b&&b.nodeType?b.ownerDocument||b:d,!0)),x.test(e[1])&&n.isPlainObject(b))for(e in b)n.isFunction(this[e])?this[e](b[e]):this.attr(e,b[e]);return this}if(f=d.getElementById(e[2]),f&&f.parentNode){if(f.id!==e[2])return A.find(a);this.length=1,this[0]=f}return this.context=d,this.selector=a,this}return a.nodeType?(this.context=this[0]=a,this.length=1,this):n.isFunction(a)?"undefined"!=typeof c.ready?c.ready(a):a(n):(void 0!==a.selector&&(this.selector=a.selector,this.context=a.context),n.makeArray(a,this))};C.prototype=n.fn,A=n(d);var D=/^(?:parents|prev(?:Until|All))/,E={children:!0,contents:!0,next:!0,prev:!0};n.fn.extend({has:function(a){var b,c=n(a,this),d=c.length;return this.filter(function(){for(b=0;d>b;b++)if(n.contains(this,c[b]))return!0})},closest:function(a,b){for(var c,d=0,e=this.length,f=[],g=w.test(a)||"string"!=typeof a?n(a,b||this.context):0;e>d;d++)for(c=this[d];c&&c!==b;c=c.parentNode)if(c.nodeType<11&&(g?g.index(c)>-1:1===c.nodeType&&n.find.matchesSelector(c,a))){f.push(c);break}return this.pushStack(f.length>1?n.uniqueSort(f):f)},index:function(a){return a?"string"==typeof a?n.inArray(this[0],n(a)):n.inArray(a.jquery?a[0]:a,this):this[0]&&this[0].parentNode?this.first().prevAll().length:-1},add:function(a,b){return this.pushStack(n.uniqueSort(n.merge(this.get(),n(a,b))))},addBack:function(a){return this.add(null==a?this.prevObject:this.prevObject.filter(a))}});function F(a,b){do a=a[b];while(a&&1!==a.nodeType);return a}n.each({parent:function(a){var b=a.parentNode;return b&&11!==b.nodeType?b:null},parents:function(a){return u(a,"parentNode")},parentsUntil:function(a,b,c){return u(a,"parentNode",c)},next:function(a){return F(a,"nextSibling")},prev:function(a){return F(a,"previousSibling")},nextAll:function(a){return u(a,"nextSibling")},prevAll:function(a){return u(a,"previousSibling")},nextUntil:function(a,b,c){return u(a,"nextSibling",c)},prevUntil:function(a,b,c){return u(a,"previousSibling",c)},siblings:function(a){return v((a.parentNode||{}).firstChild,a)},children:function(a){return v(a.firstChild)},contents:function(a){return n.nodeName(a,"iframe")?a.contentDocument||a.contentWindow.document:n.merge([],a.childNodes)}},function(a,b){n.fn[a]=function(c,d){var e=n.map(this,b,c);return"Until"!==a.slice(-5)&&(d=c),d&&"string"==typeof d&&(e=n.filter(d,e)),this.length>1&&(E[a]||(e=n.uniqueSort(e)),D.test(a)&&(e=e.reverse())),this.pushStack(e)}});var G=/\S+/g;function H(a){var b={};return n.each(a.match(G)||[],function(a,c){b[c]=!0}),b}n.Callbacks=function(a){a="string"==typeof a?H(a):n.extend({},a);var b,c,d,e,f=[],g=[],h=-1,i=function(){for(e=a.once,d=b=!0;g.length;h=-1){c=g.shift();while(++h<f.length)f[h].apply(c[0],c[1])===!1&&a.stopOnFalse&&(h=f.length,c=!1)}a.memory||(c=!1),b=!1,e&&(f=c?[]:"")},j={add:function(){return f&&(c&&!b&&(h=f.length-1,g.push(c)),function d(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){n.isFunction(c)?a.unique&&j.has(c)||f.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==n.type(c)&&d(c)})}(arguments),c&&!b&&i()),this},remove:function(){return n.each(arguments,function(a,b){var c;while((c=n.inArray(b,f,c))>-1)f.splice(c,1),h>=c&&h--}),this},has:function(a){return a?n.inArray(a,f)>-1:f.length>0},empty:function(){return f&&(f=[]),this},disable:function(){return e=g=[],f=c="",this},disabled:function(){return!f},lock:function(){return e=!0,c||j.disable(),this},locked:function(){return!!e},fireWith:function(a,c){return e||(c=c||[],c=[a,c.slice?c.slice():c],g.push(c),b||i()),this},fire:function(){return j.fireWith(this,arguments),this},fired:function(){return!!d}};return j},n.extend({Deferred:function(a){var b=[["resolve","done",n.Callbacks("once memory"),"resolved"],["reject","fail",n.Callbacks("once memory"),"rejected"],["notify","progress",n.Callbacks("memory")]],c="pending",d={state:function(){return c},always:function(){return e.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this},then:function(){var a=arguments;return n.Deferred(function(c){n.each(b,function(b,f){var g=n.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().progress(c.notify).done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject):c[f[0]+"With"](this===d?c.promise():this,g?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()},promise:function(a){return null!=a?n.extend(a,d):d}},e={};return d.pipe=d.then,n.each(b,function(a,f){var g=f[2],h=f[3];d[f[1]]=g.add,h&&g.add(function(){c=h},b[1^a][2].disable,b[2][2].lock),e[f[0]]=function(){return e[f[0]+"With"](this===e?d:this,arguments),this},e[f[0]+"With"]=g.fireWith}),d.promise(e),a&&a.call(e,e),e},when:function(a){var b=0,c=e.call(arguments),d=c.length,f=1!==d||a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?d:0,g=1===f?a:n.Deferred(),h=function(a,b,c){return function(d){b[a]=this,c[a]=arguments.length>1?e.call(arguments):d,c===i?g.notifyWith(b,c):--f||g.resolveWith(b,c)}},i,j,k;if(d>1)for(i=new Array(d),j=new Array(d),k=new Array(d);d>b;b++)c[b]&&n.isFunction(c[b].promise)?c[b].promise().progress(h(b,j,i)).done(h(b,k,c)).fail(g.reject):--f;return f||g.resolveWith(k,c),g.promise()}});var I;n.fn.ready=function(a){return n.ready.promise().done(a),this},n.extend({isReady:!1,readyWait:1,holdReady:function(a){a?n.readyWait++:n.ready(!0)},ready:function(a){(a===!0?--n.readyWait:n.isReady)||(n.isReady=!0,a!==!0&&--n.readyWait>0||(I.resolveWith(d,[n]),n.fn.triggerHandler&&(n(d).triggerHandler("ready"),n(d).off("ready"))))}});function J(){d.addEventListener?(d.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",K),a.removeEventListener("load",K)):(d.detachEvent("onreadystatechange",K),a.detachEvent("onload",K))}function K(){(d.addEventListener||"load"===a.event.type||"complete"===d.readyState)&&(J(),n.ready())}n.ready.promise=function(b){if(!I)if(I=n.Deferred(),"complete"===d.readyState||"loading"!==d.readyState&&!d.documentElement.doScroll)a.setTimeout(n.ready);else if(d.addEventListener)d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",K),a.addEventListener("load",K);else{d.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",K),a.attachEvent("onload",K);var c=!1;try{c=null==a.frameElement&&d.documentElement}catch(e){}c&&c.doScroll&&!function f(){if(!n.isReady){try{c.doScroll("left")}catch(b){return a.setTimeout(f,50)}J(),n.ready()}}()}return I.promise(b)},n.ready.promise();var L;for(L in n(l))break;l.ownFirst="0"===L,l.inlineBlockNeedsLayout=!1,n(function(){var a,b,c,e;c=d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],c&&c.style&&(b=d.createElement("div"),e=d.createElement("div"),e.style.cssText="position:absolute;border:0;width:0;height:0;top:0;left:-9999px",c.appendChild(e).appendChild(b),"undefined"!=typeof b.style.zoom&&(b.style.cssText="display:inline;margin:0;border:0;padding:1px;width:1px;zoom:1",l.inlineBlockNeedsLayout=a=3===b.offsetWidth,a&&(c.style.zoom=1)),c.removeChild(e))}),function(){var a=d.createElement("div");l.deleteExpando=!0;try{delete a.test}catch(b){l.deleteExpando=!1}a=null}();var M=function(a){var b=n.noData[(a.nodeName+" ").toLowerCase()],c=+a.nodeType||1;return 1!==c&&9!==c?!1:!b||b!==!0&&a.getAttribute("classid")===b},N=/^(?:\{[\w\W]*\}|\[[\w\W]*\])$/,O=/([A-Z])/g;function P(a,b,c){if(void 0===c&&1===a.nodeType){var d="data-"+b.replace(O,"-$1").toLowerCase();if(c=a.getAttribute(d),"string"==typeof c){try{c="true"===c?!0:"false"===c?!1:"null"===c?null:+c+""===c?+c:N.test(c)?n.parseJSON(c):c}catch(e){}n.data(a,b,c)}el
```

Este é o resultado do LoadProduct?QUERY= phrase no console do chrome:

```
jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET"localhost:9595/LoadProduct?QUERY=CA";
```

E aqui está o log da chamada:

```
26/04 13:03:41 | SELECT ID,SKUCODE,DESCRIPTION,ACTIVE FROM  VW_MOB_PRODUCT WHERE SKUCODE like '%C%' OR DESCRIPTION like '%C%'
```

Aqui o retorno, este é um exemplo de retorno pois o Json é dinamico.

```
[{"skuCode":"15004","description":"POLO EM M/MALHA ALEKIDS CAR","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":7},{"skuCode":"15019","description":"POLO EM M/ MALHA ALEKIDS FIRE 4","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":10},{"skuCode":"15064","description":"REGATA EM COTTON MANGA RENDA ADORABLE","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":23},{"skuCode":"15024","description":"CJ POLO EM M/MALHA E BERMUDA EM TECIDO SARJA XADREZ","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":38},{"skuCode":"15027","description":"CJ CAMISETA EM M/MALHA E BERMUDA EM TACTEL HEAD 0472","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":45},{"skuCode":"15040","description":"REGATA EM M/MALHA ADRENALINE WHEELS","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":77},{"skuCode":"15084","description":"CJ BLUSA E LEGUING EM COTTON LAÇOS","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":78},{"skuCode":"15041","description":"CJ POLO EM M/MALHA E BERMUDA TECIDO EM SARJA POLO TEAM","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":79},{"skuCode":"15042","description":"CJ POLO EM M/MALHA E BERMUDA TECIDO EM SARJA 38 ALK","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":82},{"skuCode":"15043","description":"CJ CAMISETA  EM M/MALHA E BERMUDA TECIDO EM TACTEL DINO","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":84},{"skuCode":"15044","description":"CJ CAMISETA  EM M/MALHA E BERMUDA TECIDO EM TACTEL XADREZ","idMeasureUnit":0,"idCategory":0,"idCollection":0,"active":true,"obs":"","id":88}]
```

Comment: As vezes o browser aponta o erro para um arquivo de alguma lib, mas, geralmente este erro é causado por consequência de problema no seu código.

Comment: De um exemplo de retorno da requisição para "LoadProduct?QUERY=" + phrase".

Comment: Editei a questão, mais alguma coisa pra dar uma luz ai? Se eu retirar o script do EasyAutocomplete do main.jsp o erro não acontece. Já tentei usar scripts de outras fontes, mas todos apresentam o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você não postou o retorno que eu falei ... mas de qualquer jeito, olha: http://easyautocomplete.com/ aqui tem um exemplo do formato de dados que é aceito: [{"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},... Você está fornecendo dados dessa forma, nessa url que eu citei?

Comment: Sim o formato acredito que esteja correto, até porque ele me retorna a description conforme eu quero que faça. Mas aparece esse erro no console do chrome.

Comment: Mas você pode checar esse retorno e comparar com o JSON do site? Pode ser que não esteja exatamente igual ... em uma situação dessa, é bem provável que o problema seja algo assim ....

Comment: Este retorno que coloquei aí é o retorno do meu LoadProduct. Apenas coloquei nele uma query qualquer para mostrar o resultado e cortei alguns objetos Json para poder postar aqui. Mas o retorno é esse ai mesmo.

Comment: Então cara, o componente usa "name":value, "id":id. Você vai ter que fazer tua query gerar um retorno assim.

Comment: Qual campo você quer que aparece no autocomplete?

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O JSON que você está retornando não parece estar no mesmo formato do que aquele que é utilizado para exemplifar o uso desse componente. Para sugerir outra forma de escrever essa query, é necessário saber qual é o campo que você quer que aparece no autocompletar. Vamos supor que seja `skuCode`:

```
SELECT skuCode as name, id as code FROM  VW_MOB_PRODUCT WHE....
```

O resultado dessa query vai trazer os dados no mesmo formato do exemplo encontrado aqui:http://easyautocomplete.com/

> [    {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},    {"name": "Aland
>   Islands", "code": "AX"},    {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},....

Comment: Quer dizer que só posso ter dois 'atributos' dentro no meu objeto Json? No caso do exemplo que estais passando seria apenas dois "name" e "code" é esse o problema?

Comment: Claro, a única coisa que o componente vai utilizar é o campo para completar, o resto é lixo. Mas não sei se daria erro, ou ele iria ignorar caso tivesse os outros campos. Mas tenho certeza que ele espera um campo "name" e outro "code".

Comment: No meu caso não que o resto fosse lixo, eu na verdade gostaria que o autocomplete desse a opção de completar para qualquer informação do objeto contido nesse Json. Mas se só posso utilizar dois atributos, paciência.